# Adding a record into a plsql associative array inside a loop?

Tags: collections, plsql

Definition of record :

```
TYPE REC_ITEM_ACC is record (
      item_account_id   manual_transaction.item_account_id%TYPE    
     ,tag_id manual_transaction.tag_id%TYPE  
     ,change_in_balance bank_account.current_balance%type
  );
  V_REC_ITEM_ACC  REC_ITEM_ACC;
```

Definition of table :

```
TYPE TAB_ITEM_ACC is table of REC_ITEM_ACC 
index by PLS_INTEGER;
V_TAB_ITEM_ACC TAB_ITEM_ACC;
```

Inside a loop ,v_man_txn_rec_table is another table of records , with a field 'item_account_id', the select into query is putting data in v_man_txn_rec_table table,i want to do something like this (the table/associative-array is indexed using the item_account_id field of the record):

```
V_REC_ITEM_ACC.item_account_id := some value from select into query
V_REC_ITEM_ACC.tag_id := some value from select into query
V_REC_ITEM_ACC.change_in_balance := some value from select into query     
V_TAB_ITEM_ACC(v_man_txn_rec_table(i).item_account_id) :=  V_REC_ITEM_ACC
```

here in the loop , is only the reference of V_REC_ITEM_ACC going to be added into the associative-array/table V_TAB_ITEM_ACC , or will a deep copy will be performed , is there a better way to insert record elements into a table ,here i can not use a select into to insert into the table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Items put into a table like this are deep-copied.  [SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ad0de/5)

Share and enjoy.